# Regular Expression matching parentheses in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to get string in parentheses, even the parentheses in parentheses.

Example: `int main() {printf ("hallo world"); return 0 ; }`

Result:

```
>>> ()
    {printf ("hallo world"); return 0 ; }
    ("hallo world")
```

The result is get every parentheses in string. I've been trying for hours, mind you my regular expression knowledge isn't what I'd like it to be :-) so any help will be gratefully received. I use python to implementation this.

Comment: Of those many hours of trying what did you come up with?

Comment: I don't see a single line of regex or python code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To find all such matches use the following, as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/xL9mE5/1) at Regex 101:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\("(.*?)"\)', string)
```

Comment: There are apparently potentially parens inside parens also

Comment: Which would be matched by the `.` character, no?

Comment: depends on how they are nested

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Edit as you deem necessary.

Comment: I have no idea what it would be unless the OP provides some examples.